# Testing AJAX-intensive Rails application with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, testing, rspec

I'm writing a very AJAX-intensive application using Rails 3.0.4, and testing it with RSpec. Most of my controller actions just respond to a "js" format, ie:

```
respond_to do |format|
  f.js
end
```

and other respond to json. I found how to JSON output, but I'm not really sure how to test the javascript output from the other actions.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd checkout [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to handle testing of javascript/ajax functionality of your website.

Checkout [this popular slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/alexchaffee/fullstack-webapp-testing-with-selenium-and-rails) on testing Rails apps with Selenium.

Comment: There's also a railscast that just came out about using rspec, capybara, and selenium when necessary: http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara